# Image of convex hull

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis

I came across a problem that I could simplify, if I knew that this is true:

Let $A:= conv(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map. Does this imply that the image of $A$ is the convex hull $conv(T(x),T(y),T(z))$?

Does anybody know if this is correct?

Comment: Yes. For for any number of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think a proof could be like this:
If T is a linear map, then it has the following form:
T(x)=ax for every vector $ x e R^n $ , $ a e R^n $. Then 
take a vector w e T(A). Now it is w = T(q)=aq =a(λχ+λ'y+λ"z)=λax+λ'ay+λ"az=λΤ(x)+λ'Τ(y)+λ"Τ(z) e conv(T(x),T(y),T(z)) , where λ+λ'+λ"=1 (λ_i>=0).

Now, if w e conv(T(x),T(y),T(z))  w= λΤ(χ)+λ'T(y)+ λ"Τ(z)=a(λχ+λ'y+λ"z)=Τ(q) for q e conv(x,y,z).So w e T(A).

That might conclude the proof. I don't know if you have to take cases for A=3-simplex or not but it seems to me right.